# How to plot graphs in Latex using sagetex

Tags: sagetex

Now I have got the file sage-plots-for-example.tex in sage that contains all the plots. Do I also have to put all these .eps and .png  into the same folder as the tex file?

Comment: If you have run 'pdflatex ...' (or 'latex ...') and then 'sage ...', the pictures should be in the right place automatically. You shouldn't have to move them.